# Escape wildcard characters in LIKE condition

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

When you use a LIKE operator in a [search condition](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html):

```
<?php
array('OR' => array(
    array('Post.title LIKE' => '%one%'),
    array('Post.title LIKE' => '%two%')
))
```

... is there a built-in mechanism in CakePHP to escape wildcard characters so you can search for literal `%` or `_` or simply inject search terms from untrusted sources such as forms?

```
<?php
array('OR' => array(
    array('Post.title LIKE' => '%' . $this->foo('100%') . '%'),
    array('Post.title LIKE' => '%' . $this->foo('red_apples') . '%')
                                            ^^^
))
```

Comment: would `str_replace(array('%', '_'), array('\%', '\_'), '100%_');` be enough?

Comment: It actually isn't. All "\"'s get properly escaped and you end up searching for a literal `\%` rather than `%`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually figured out that I can simply use prepared statements explicitly:

```
<?php
$query = array('OR' => array(
    array(
        'Post.title LIKE ?' => array(
            '%' . $this->escapeLike('100%') . '%'),
        ),
    ),
    array(
        'Post.title LIKE ?' => array(
            '%' . $this->escapeLike('red_apples') . '%'),
        ),
    ),
);
```

... or, whenever the DBMS does not have a default separator or we prefer to set ours:

```
<?php
$separator = '|';
$query = array('OR' => array(
    array(
        'Post.title LIKE ? ESCAPE ?' => array(
            '%' . $this->escapeLike('100%', $separator) . '%'),
            $separator
        ),
    ),
    array(
        'Post.title LIKE ? ESCAPE ?' => array(
            '%' . $this->escapeLike('red_apples', $separator) . '%'),
            $separator
        ),
    ),
);
```

My `escapeLike()` method is currently this (that was never the hard part):

```
/**
 * Escapes LIKE wildcard characters
 *
 * @param string $text
 * @param string $escape_character
 * @return string
 */
protected function escapeLike ($text, $escape_character='\\') {
    return strtr($text, array(
        '%'               => $escape_character . '%',
        '_'               => $escape_character . '_',
        $escape_character => $escape_character . $escape_character,
    ));
}
```

I implemented it in `AppModel` for simplicity (at least in my project).

This works on CakePHP/2.5 with the MySQL adapter (no idea of other scenarios).

Answer (score 2):

```
App::uses('Sanitize', 'Utility'); // load Sanitize utility        
$db = $this->Model->getDataSource(); // get the datasource
$this->Model->find('all', array(
    'conditions' => array(
        'name LIKE' => $db->expression('\'%' . addcslashes(Sanitize::escape($userInput), '%_') . '%\'')
    )
));
```

When we use `$db->expression`, cake does no escaping for us. So we manually do the escaping using the `Sanitize` utility and then replace `%` and `_` with `\%` and `\_`. Not sure if this is 100% safe, let me know if you see that its not so I can update the answer.

You'll want to create your own method that will do this whole thing for you to keep it DRY

Edit: Replaced `str_replace` with `addcslashes`

Edit2: Realized I over-complicated this. If you want cake to not escape you can also just provide a value with no key. Ex.

```
'conditions' => array(
    'Post.title LIKE \'%' . addcslashes(Sanitize::escape($userInput), '%_') . '%\'',
)
```

Both ways produce

```
`Post`.`title` LIKE '%100\'\%\_%'
```

for the user input `$userInput = "100'%_";`

Comment: To whoever downvoted the answer without further explanation: being new to CakePHP, I'd particularly appreciate if you explained what's wrong with it.

Comment: Yes, please do give a reason. I suspect it is the same person going around downvoted many of my answers - at least provide and explanation, thank you.

Comment: Yes, but I didn't report back yet because I couldn't make it work. CakePHP back-quotes the complete `Post.title` expression rather than `Post` and `title` separately :-?

Comment: You mean you get `\`Post.title\`` rather than `\`Post\`.\`title\``? If you want, catch me on #cakephp in freenode.

Comment: That's it. I wasn't able to type it in the Stack Overflow editor :)

Comment: I setup my test like so http://bin.cakephp.org/view/349644663 and I get what I'm pretty sure is the expected result. I'm on #cakephp so we can try to debug it there if you'd like (same nick in irc)

Comment: To sum up: CakePHP does not have such feature and you need to write your own workaround. Thus I'm accepting your answer—I couldn't make it work but it was probably my fault (I admit I gave up, there's more important stuff to code :)

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use [Data Sanitization class](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/sanitize.html#data-sanitization) to achieve the same. Hope it will work for you.

Comment: I browsed the book and the API and I couldn't find anything that applies to my problem. Unless I'm missing something, the `Sanitize` class is basically a poor HTML processor with some MySQL-only additions to skip prepared statements.